# Einstein Bot Rules not Executing

Tags: einstein, chat

I have created a simple chat bot.  I am asking if the customer wants to continue.  I have created a new variable called Yes_No of type Boolean to store the answer from the question.  I have then created a rule to check the answer.  If answer No, but the dialog continues to the next set and not direct to the other dialog as expected.

Any thoughts will be most appreciated

I have provided screen shots below

Clear down the variables before starting
[image: Clear down the variables before starting]

Ask the question and save the answer to the boolean variable Yes No
[image: Ask the question]

Show result for debugging purposes.  And the rule. If False then go to another dialog
[image: Rule to check answer to question, and if No, then go to another dialog]

Result on the chat bot.  Show that it is continuing and not going to the other dialog
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, I was using Call Dialog not Redirect to Dialog, doh